# What software to use for Event Storming?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-storming

With regard to Event Sourcing and Domain Driven Design, I'm looking for a good software solution to help my team model our Aggregates electronically during an Event Storming session.

I have considered simple sticky note applications but they leave a lot to be desired such as the ability to save and share.

So what would you recommend as a good Event Storming software?

Comment: While I'm not a fan of the Trello interface, it may be the closer tool to what we use in real life with the ability to share, assign, edit, or remove easily. There are also plugins which can make your life easier with it.

Comment: A central concept of Event Storming is that any participant is equal and everybody can put their ideas/events onto the wall simultaneously, i.e., the complete open freedom while modelling. If you are going to do this in software, probably even with a single central person being responsible for input, you a very much limiting the very idea of ES.

Comment: Providing an accessible medium for modelling processes and events is far more important than storing the outcome.  Just buy a cheap digital camera with a high resolution and take pictures of the walls, I think that's what Ziobrando does.  Introducing software into the process would just slow it down and make it less accessible.

Comment: I agree with you @AlexanderLanger. I would be limiting my team's ideas.... However my challenges include set up every session, losing sticky notes etc. Photographing the notes have actually worked for us till now, but it would be nice to refer back to previous sessions. Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you only get opinionated answers. Tools that you really need to consider:

1. Paper roll, preferably plotter roll since it is dense enough and wide enough. For more vertical space put two strips, one below the other. Take a photo when you are done, share it with others. It is OK to scrap the roll since for the next session it would be beneficial to re-create the picture again and it will be better (see WET - write everything twice)
2. Online tools that have sticky notes of different colours and sizes. These should only be used if you have a distributed online session. I know two online tools that allow real-time collaboration, we use one and tried another, which is also very good. You choose yourself. I do not work for any of those.

- [Miro](https://miro.com)
- [Conceptboard](https://conceptboard.com/)
- [Mural](http://mural.ly)

Comment: Thanx for your suggestions @Alexey. I think these will work great for what I needed

Answer (score 1):

How about a "whiteboard"? I found it actually quite easier to create a very large image with a very dark gray background and simply use Paint to draw on top of it. Other devs were able to add their ideas to it and Save As... so that the original file was not overwritten.

Does it make sense?